# What are the .ini files in /etc/php5/conf.d folder for?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, configuration

I get that the .ini files in `/etc/php5/cli` have to do with CLI usage of PHP, the files in `/etc/php5/fpm` are about FastCGI/FPM aspect of PHP, but what about the .ini files located in `/etc/php5/conf.d`?

Comment: global .ini directives, that apply to all instances of php, regardless of how/where they're executed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From `/usr/share/doc/php5-common/README.Debian.gz` (on an Ubuntu system with PHP installed):

> Additionally, each SAPI is configured with the compile-time option
>
> ```
>     --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php5/$SAPI/conf.d
> ```
>
> which for all SAPI's is actually a symlink pointing to a central
>   directory /etc/php5/conf.d.  Any file found in this directory ending
>   in .ini will be treated as a configuration file by the php SAPI.
>
> The rationale with this method is that each SAPI can thus be
>   identically configured with a minimal amount of conffile handling, but
>   at the same time if you want to have SAPI-specific configuration, you
>   can just remove the symlink.

Comment: If you have a new question, then try using "Ask Question" instead of "Add Comment" but [search first](https://superuser.com/questions/564995/what-is-the-php-config-ini-files-prefix-good-for)

Answer (score 21):

Those files will overwrite the settings in php.ini. Putting config stuff here allows you to have custom settings while keeping updates simpler: if you modify php.ini itself then you either have to retain the old php.ini or overwrite it when you update PHP. If you keep your custom settings in, eg. `conf.d/local.ini` then you can update PHP easily while retaining any environment-specific settings.

(Credit due to [this blog post](http://www.phpdeveloper.org.uk/overriding-default-php-settings-in-debian-and-ubuntu/))

Comment: jupp thats what i was looking for :)