# What could cause xdebug's remote_host setting to be ignored

Tags: php, xdebug

My `xdebug.remote_host` setting gets completely ignored, and another host is used instead.

In my `/etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini`:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_host=10.0.4.89
xdebug.remote_port=8020
xdebug.idekey=albumview--php-fpm
xdebug.remote_log=/var/www/albumviewer-api/output/xdebug.log
```

And yet, when I run a cli script, I see this in the logs:

```
Log opened at 2019-02-15 10:19:27
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 192.168.2.54:8020.
E: Time-out connecting to client (Waited: 200 ms). :-(
Log closed at 2019-02-15 10:19:27
```

Restarting the docker container has no effect. What am i missing? Why does it try to connect to 192.163.2.54 and not the ip-address I specified?

Comment: Can you get xdebug section from phpinfo() ?
I guess there's another file (most likely `/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/xdebug.ini`) that overrides your settings of php.ini

Comment: Thank you @Andrew. I never thought to check `phpinfo()`. There was indeed another file overriding the setting.

If you place this comment as an answer, I'll award you the points :-)

Comment: It is done. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you get xdebug section from `phpinfo()` ?

I guess there's another file (most likely `/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/xdebug.ini` ) that overrides your settings of `php.ini`

And here is related explaination [What the .ini files in /etc/php5/conf.d folder are for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383806/what-the-ini-files-in-etc-php5-conf-d-folder-are-for)